# Read directory and save contents of files to new file in Perl

Tags: perl, file, parsing

I want to save the contents of some files into a new file, and I do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my ($dir) = @ARGV;
my @files = glob "details/*";
my $filename = 'target.txt';

for my $file (@files) {
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file($file);
  my @opacity = $tree->findnodes_as_strings('//div[@class="opacity description"]');
  open my $fh, '>>', $filename;
  print $fh for @opacity; 
}
```

Unfortunately it will not work. And I dont understand why?

Comment: `"it will not work"` is a very bad way to describe your problem. It doesn't really say anything. Try using some debug printing messages using `Data::Dumper` and then return when you have more information about your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the return value of `open`:

   ```
   open my $fh ">>", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
   ```

   This can provide invaluable insights when “something isn't working”.
2. Your syntax for `print` is ambiguous. Use `print` or `say` like

   ```
   print FILEHANDLE LIST
   print {EXPR} LIST     # EXPR has to produce a filehandle object
   print LIST            # prints to the `select`ed filehandle, usually STDOUT
   print                 # prints $_ by default
   ```

   So you want to explicitly specify what you are printing, and probably also add a newline after each element in `@opacity`. So either

   ```
   print {$fh} "$_\n" for @opacity;
   ```

   or `use feature 'say'` (perl 5.10 and better):

   ```
   say {$fh} $_ for @opacity;
   ```

Comment: can you tell me why it strips the tags?

Comment: It prints only the text content of the element because you are calling `findnodes_as_strings`, which I put in my solution to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646764) because that is what your regular expression did. If you explain what it is you actually want, perhaps in a new question, then we can help you.

Comment: @Borodin I simply want to do what the script does , but I want to keep all the html tags.